# Drupal 8, "view ui query" to drupal code query api ?

Tags: views, 8, database

When we build a view from the view ui, we can show what is the "hard query" is executed, example :

```
SELECT node__field_house_count_added.field_house_count_added_value AS node__field_house_count_added_field_house_count_added_value, node_field_data.nid AS nid
FROM 
{node_field_data} node_field_data
INNER JOIN {node__field_house_tags} node__field_house_tags_value_0 ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_house_tags_value_0.entity_id AND node__field_house_tags_value_0.field_house_tags_target_id = '4'
INNER JOIN {node__field_house_tags} node__field_house_tags_value_1 ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_house_tags_value_1.entity_id AND node__field_house_tags_value_1.field_house_tags_target_id = '5'
INNER JOIN {node__field_house_tags} node__field_house_tags_value_2 ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_house_tags_value_2.entity_id AND node__field_house_tags_value_2.field_house_tags_target_id = '16'
INNER JOIN {node__field_house_tags} node__field_house_tags_value_3 ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_house_tags_value_3.entity_id AND node__field_house_tags_value_3.field_house_tags_target_id = '6'
LEFT JOIN {node__field_house_count_added} node__field_house_count_added ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_house_count_added.entity_id AND (node__field_house_count_added.deleted = '0' AND node__field_house_count_added.langcode = node_field_data.langcode)
WHERE ((( (node__field_house_tags_value_0.field_house_tags_target_id = '4') AND (node__field_house_tags_value_1.field_house_tags_target_id = '5') AND (node__field_house_tags_value_2.field_house_tags_target_id = '16') AND (node__field_house_tags_value_3.field_house_tags_target_id = '6') )))
ORDER BY node__field_house_count_added_field_house_count_added_value DESC
LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0
```

Is there a way for get quickly the query, but in the query api format ? Like :

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u')
  ->condition('u.uid', 0, '<>')
  ->fields('u', array('uid', 'name', 'status', 'created', 'access'))
  ->range(0, 50);
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

You're also not supposed to write a query directly against entity or field tables yourself. Use the entity query API instead:

https://www.sitepoint.com/drupal-8-version-entityfieldquery/

```
$uids = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
  ->condition('uid', 0, '<>',
  ->range(0, 50)
  ->execute();
```